# Sharing controller between views

Tags: python, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I have a frame which holds 2 views. I want to use a common controller for both of them but not instantiate 2 controllers. How do i achieve this? Singleton? Send the controller as an argument?

Note, the controller will hold temporary data (*bad idea?*) that will be sent away on command. That's why i only want one controller object. Don't be shy to suggest other design ideas.

*First view*

```
Class ViewAlpha
    def __init_(self, parent):
        self.controller = Controller()

    def on_click(self, event):
        self.controller.do_this(event.data)
```

*Second view*

```
Class ViewBeta
    def __init_(self, parent):
        self.controller = Controller()

    def on_click(self, event):
        self.controller.do_this(event.data)
```

*Controller*

```
Class Controller
    def __init_(self):
        self.client = Client()

    def do_this(self, data):
        self.client.store(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing things as arguments, just like in your code, is the most common solution to problems like this. If you only need the `do_this` -method, you can even just pass the method:

```
beta = ViewBeta(controller.do_this)
```

Comment: But where do i instantiate the controller? There are several methods that will be used, the above was just a simplified example.

Comment: In the same place you instantiate the views. Or, you can pass the controller to some object that instantiates the views.

Comment: Of course, silly me having a clog in my head.  I re modeled my design and now my views uses the same controller.

Comment: @Poonuts: Many good programmers tell you to code first in a linear fashion and only after that refactor into functions and structs. Implemented in that way, abstractions can't get in your way so badly.